# Emulate a printer in pc

Tags: c#, .net, printers

I have made an desktop application using C# to make `ID card` .And i am required to add functionality of printing an ID card .Basically i just make an image in a win form which will be eventually printed  using.

But as i have no printer,i can't test my code to see if it prints something.

Is there any emulator or software that emulates a printer in windows,so that i cant test my application?

[image: Sameple Id card layout]

This is a sample what i need to print.It wiil be in a win form.

And another thing. How can i maintain size of the id card while printing. Say id card size should be in 2inch * 3.5inch. How can i make sure it will print same size?

Comment: google 'free pdf printer'

Comment: eg http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php it acts like a physical printer but saves to pdf

Comment: Others have provided two basic approaches, both work well--99% of my test printing is done this way.  I would advise trying it once to a real printer (take the file to the printer) just to make sure you're not doing formatting mistakes that aren't obvious on the screen.  (We aren't used to margins on the screen, it's easy to mess them up.)

Comment: I'd expect O- to be a blood group rather than an ID number

Comment: I edited my question.can any of you guys answere that?

Comment: You have two questions here, the first of which should be closed as off-topic since you're asking us to recommend a tool. Nobody can answer the second question without seeing your code. For example, if you're drawing using pixels as size units your image will not be the same size on printers of different resolutions.

Answer (score 4):

Try print to PDF file to check that Your application works. For example You can use "PDF Creator" under Windows OS's. It is the easiest way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Microsoft XPS printer driver](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/print-to-xps-document-writer) that ships with Windows (since Vista, but available for Windows XP)

> The XPS Document Writer allows you to create .xps files using any
>   program that you can print from in Windows. Print to the XPS Document
>   Writer when you want to create, send, and share or publish documents
>   that you do not want other people to modify, or when you want to print
>   a document or display it online exactly as it appears on your screen.
>   It's also a good idea to create an XPS document for files that contain
>   graphics or illustrations that might otherwise display differently in
>   print than online or on computers with different monitors.

[image]

Once you click OK, you're prompted for the file path to save it to.